# Change type column

Tags: mysql, sql

how in mysql, i can change the range of DECIMAL in already created table

```
CREATE TABLE Confectionery (
Price DECIMAL(20),
DateOfMaking DATE
);
```

I want to change it to: DECIMAL (5,2)

Comment: mysql  or sql-server  .. ?????

Comment: Removed [tag:sql-server] tag because the OP's question says "in mysql..."

Answer (score 1):

for mysql you could try

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY Price DECIMAL (5,2);
```